# How to format this string into valid json with js replace?

Tags: javascript, json, str-replace, stringify

Been at this for a while but I can't seem to target all of the \n in the string and convert them into line breaks for proper JSON formatting.

```
   .replace(new RegExp('\n','g'), '\\\\n');
```

Here's the first part of the string:

```
"{\n \"listing\": [\n {\n \"name\": \"blah blah\"\n },\n {\n \"name\": \"blah blah blah\"\n },\n {\n \"name\": \"next blah blah
```

Comment: Seems like you have it backwards, you want to replace `\\\\n` with `\n`...

Comment: '\\\\n' is two backslashes followed by an n. I think you are wanting to replace '\\n' with '\n'